# Real and Imaginary Parts of a Complex Valued Rational Fraction

Tags: complex-numbers

I just want to know how to separate the real and the imaginary part of the following complex rational number. The purpose of this is for me to be able to compute the phase and gain margin of the following transfer function.

$H(s)=\frac{1-s}{s^2+s+1}$ or 
$H(jw)=\frac{1-jw}{(jw)^2+jw+1}$

I know that I needed to find the magnitude of the following transfer function and I am having trouble to do so because of the denominator.

Will appreciate any help you may provide

Comment: Are you supposed to know the real and imaginary parts of $s$ and/or $jw$?  I you know how to find the real and imaginary parts of $\frac {a+bi}{c + di}$ where $a,b,c,d$ are real?  By multiplying by conjugates? ($\frac {a+bi}{c+di}=\frac {(a+bi)(c-di)}{(c+di)(c-di)}=\frac {(ac+bd)+(bc-ad)i}{c^2 + d^2} = \frac {ac +bd}{c^2+d^2}+\frac{bd-ad}{c^2 + d^2} i$?) Just do that.

Comment: Do you want to find the real and imaginary parts or would finding the modulus and phase by other means do?

Comment: Hi, I just need to find the real and imaginary part of jw as it was converted to the complex plane (s=jw). My problem is how would I do that for the denominator. I tried to take the roots (i.e. s+0.5+j0.866 and s+0.5-j0.866) but I was having trouble of what conjugate to multiply to get its imaginary part.

Comment: If you can suggest other means to do it by manual calculation, would be very glad to know how to do it. Thanks

Comment: Is $w$ real valued? Is $j^2=-1$? Are you only interested in $|H(jw)|$?

Comment: Hi @Did, yeah w is real valued j2=−1. Thanks

Comment: Then use $$|H(jw)|=\frac{|1-jw|}{|1-w^2+jw|}=\frac{\sqrt{1-w^2}}{\sqrt{(1-w^2)^2+w^2}}$$

Comment: Thanks, Ill try this and see. How did u derived this? What did you multiply to get the magnitude? How about the complex part? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The comments on the question provide a good amount of insight to finding a solution, but I noticed there were still unanswered questions on how to solve the original problem.

As you said, the straightforward way is to find the real and imaginary parts,  then use the Pythagorean formula to find the magnitude.  separating into real and imaginary parts is usually done as @fleablood stated by multiplying the top and bottom of the fraction by the denominator's complex conjugate.  Then, the fraction can be separated into real and imaginary parts by the terms in the numerator.

In your case, let's start with the $H(j\omega)$ version of your rational function, as it seems to be what you're looking for. (It can be done but gets more complicated if you are working in the $s$ domain where $s=\sigma + j\omega$).

$$H(j\omega)=\frac{1−j\omega}{(j\omega)^2+j\omega+1}$$

The first simplification is in the denominator, as $j^2=-1$

$$H(j\omega)=\frac{1−j\omega}{-\omega^2+j\omega+1}$$

$\omega$ is a real valued number, so the complex conjugate for the denominator just has the sign of the complex term changed: $1-\omega^2-j\omega$

Now, rationalizing the fraction:

$$H(j\omega)=\frac{1−j\omega}{1-\omega^2+j\omega}\times\frac{1-\omega^2-j\omega}{1-\omega^2-j\omega}$$
$$ = \frac{j\omega^3-2\omega^2-2j\omega+1}{\omega^4-\omega^2+1}$$
$$ = \frac{-2\omega^2+1}{\omega^4-\omega^2+1}+j\frac{\omega^3-2\omega}{\omega^4-\omega^2+1}$$

With the real and imaginary parts separated, we can find the magnitude:

$$\lvert{H(j\omega)}\rvert = \sqrt{\left(\frac{-2\omega^2+1}{\omega^4-\omega^2+1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\omega^3-2\omega}{\omega^4-\omega^2+1}\right)^2}$$
$$= \sqrt{\frac{\left(-2\omega^2+1\right)^2+\left(\omega^3-2\omega\right)^2}{\left(\omega^4-\omega^2+1\right)^2}}$$
$$= \sqrt{\frac{\omega^6+1}{\left(\omega^4-\omega^2+1\right)^2}}$$
$$= \sqrt{\frac{\left(\omega^2+1\right)\left(\omega^4-\omega^2+1\right)}{\left(\omega^4-\omega^2+1\right)^2}}$$

$$\lvert{H(j\omega)}\rvert = \sqrt{\frac{\omega^2+1}{\omega^4-\omega^2+1}}$$

There may be other ways of doing the algebraic manipulation, but this seemed the most straightforward. (Note that factoring $\omega^6+1$ uses the [Sum of Cubes Identity](https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-factor-x-3-1) recognizing that $\omega^6+1 = \left(\omega^2\right)^3+1$.

The final result was verified with the *Maxima 5.43.0* `cabs` function, which results in the equivalent expression:

$$\lvert{H(j\omega)}\rvert = \sqrt{\frac{\omega^2+1}{\left(1-\omega^2\right)^2+\omega^2}}$$

Comment: Setting magnitude =1 for phase margin, $$\omega = \sqrt {2} $$ then solve phase

Comment: Ermm Setting magnitude =0 for phase margin, $$\omega = ? 
 $$ then solve phase